# Angular - Value not being passed to Modal view

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass through a value to a modal component, I followed this tutorial: https://itnext.io/creating-forms-inside-modals-with-ng-bootstrap-221e4f1f5648.

I can see the value being passed through, but not being retained on the other side. Any ideas why?

```
// Component being sent from 

openModal(millerIndex: number, farmIndex: number, view: number, millerName: string) {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalComponent);
  modalRef.componentInstance.millerIndex = millerIndex;
  modalRef.componentInstance.farmIndex = farmIndex;
  modalRef.componentInstance.view = view;
  modalRef.componentInstance.millerName = millerName;

  modalRef.result.then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

// Modal component with relevant imports

@Input() millerIndex: number;
@Input() farmIndex: number;
@Input() view: number;
@Input() millerName: string;
@Input() farmName: string;
modalTitle = '';

// Being called OnInit()
createForm() {
if (this.view === 1) {

  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    paddockCode: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    paddockArea: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    paddockOwner: new FormControl({value: this.farmName, disabled: 
    true}, Validators.required)
  });
}

// HTML inside form
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="paddock-owner">Owner</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" 
     formControlName="paddockOwner" value="{{ farmName }}" />
</div>
```

Comment: Using ngModel on Reactive Forms has been deprecated in Angular 6 and will be removed in Angular 7. I just want to display the value, but when I console.log the value it's undefined. But, being passed through as part of the modalRef the value is there.

Comment: I don't think you can use `value` on a form control when using reactive forms - you've already set it in code. And can you add your code which closes the model and passes the result back (assuming thats the console.log function you are referring to).

Comment: Inside the createFrom method I console.log the value and as mentioned it's undefined.

Comment: Can you please update your code... the code you have shown doesn't include passing the farmName in, and is missing the console.log you refer to. It makes it hard to help.

Comment: Thanks Dale I didn't realise I hadn't passed through the farmName!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dale mentioned above, I didn't pass through the farmName.

```
openModal(millerIndex: number, farmIndex: number, view: number,
  millerName: string, farmName: string) {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalComponent);
  modalRef.componentInstance.millerIndex = millerIndex;
  modalRef.componentInstance.farmIndex = farmIndex;
  modalRef.componentInstance.view = view;
  modalRef.componentInstance.millerName = millerName;
  modalRef.componentInstance.farmName = farmName;

  modalRef.result.then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```